# How can I build a Xamarin iOS app using MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, xamarin, teamcity

I have an iOS App project, builds fine in Visual Studio (paired with my Mac build host). I want to build this project using an MSBuild command, so that I can use Teamcity for my builds. (My build agent is a Windows machine which will pair with a Mac build host).

Currently I run the following command:

```
msbuild MyApp.App.iOS.csproj /t:_RemoteBuild /p:ServerAddress=macmini2.local;Configuration="Debug";Platform="iPhoneSimulator";OutputPath="C:\Projects\MySolution\MyApp.App.iOS\bin\iPhoneSimulator\Debug"
```

And this builds my 2 library projects, but it seems to fail when building my main project:

```
_GenerateBundleContentDir:
  Preparing application bundle
  Copying file from "C:\Projects\MySolution\MyApp.App.iOS\bin\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\MyApp.Business.Core.dll" to "C:\Projects\MySolution\MyApp.App.iOS\obj\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\build_package\assemblies\MyApp.Business.Core.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\Projects\MySolution\MyApp.App.iOS\bin\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\MyApp.Business.Core.pdb" to "C:\Projects\MySolution\MyApp.App.iOS\obj\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\build_package\assemblies\MyApp.Business.Core.pdb".
  Copying file from "C:\Projects\MySolution\MyApp.App.iOS\bin\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\MyApp.Business.Core.dll.mdb" to "C:\Projects\MySolution\MyApp.App.iOS\obj\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\build_package\assemblies\MyApp.Business.Core.dll.mdb".
  Copying file from "C:\Projects\MySolution\MyApp.App.iOS\bin\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\MyApp.Business.iOS.dll" to "C:\Projects\MySolution\MyApp.App.iOS\obj\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\build_package\assemblies\MyApp.Business.iOS.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\Projects\MySolution\MyApp.App.iOS\bin\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\MyApp.Business.iOS.pdb" to "C:\Projects\MySolution\MyApp.App.iOS\obj\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\build_package\assemblies\MyApp.Business.iOS.pdb".
  Copying file from "C:\Projects\MySolution\MyApp.App.iOS\bin\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\MyApp.Business.iOS.dll.mdb" to "C:\Projects\MySolution\MyApp.App.iOS\obj\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\build_package\assemblies\MyApp.Business.iOS.dll.mdb".
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.MonoTouch.Common.targets(195,3): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\Projects\MySolution\MyApp.App.iOS\bin\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\MyAppAppiOS.exe" because it was not found. [C:\Projects\MySolution\MyApp.App.iOS\MyApp.App.iOS.csproj]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment it is not possible to build Xamarin.iOS projects using msbuild (it is being worked on and in the future (not sure when) this will change).

However it seems it's possible to delegate the work to the Mac: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/44484/#Comment_44484

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you work for Xamarin? If not do you have an official source? And by the way that is somewhat alarming... How can I actually use my Windows-based teamcity agent for building xamarin projects? Am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: Yes, I work for Xamarin. I've updated the post with a proposed solution.

Comment: this is outdated. Xamarin Studio (and probably Visual Studio for Mac in the very near future) installs msbuild as a command line tool on the mac.